# Is it theoretically possible to design wormhole gates for space travel?

Tags: technology, space, space-travel, space-constructs

In the story I am writing I would like space travel to be as realistic as possible. Wormholes are a theoretical possibility but they are incredibly unstable as well as difficult to manage, but they are effective in fast travel to faraway locations. I considered the fact that in this story technology is much more advanced so anything is theoretically possible but I don't want things to be too unrealistic and in reality are completely impossible.

I thought about the typical engine attachments that would allow the entire ship to be engulfed in a wormhole but find it more unrealistic for each ship to have a wormhole engine system since it is unlikely each ship would have enough power to create a wormhole. So I thought of the possibility of wormhole gates throughout a solar system. Large, door frame shaped technology that creates and maintains a wormhole that leads to a specific location either in another solar system or somewhere else in that same solar system.

Is it possible to create technology that could stabilize a wormhole as well as create a definite destination?

Comment: 'Is it possible' questions generally make poor questions because the only way the answer is no is if you can definitely disprove something, which obviously we can't do when talking about future technology.  a lot of things we have today would have seemed impossible 500 years ago.  IMO, its your job as a writer to provide the story and world building that would make it seem possible.

Comment: Wormholes in SciFi function as a handwave for instantaneous travel in general. As such they are often mixed up with black holes and neither of them is every really portrayed realistically. You can basically do whatever you want with it as long as it sounds like some sort of portal in space...

Comment: Call 'em "space portals" or just "portals", and you should be good. I wouldn't even try to explain the science of it unless the process of inventing them is core to your story: realistic wormhole travel isn't the realm of science, or even science fiction.

Answer (score 6):

**Wormholes are acceptable scifi.**

If your company were making wormholes I would be very skeptical.  But if your fiction entails use of wormholes - sure!   Having a wormhole is a fine, familiar shorthand way to explain how your characters are zipping over enormous distances.  I thought the Stargate series was great and they are premised around wormholes exactly as you describe.  They handwaved the tech - ancient aliens, you know.  Ditto for warp drives, hyperspace; all that.  FTL of any stripe is problematic for real physics but for scifi FTL is a means to an end, the end being lots of aliens getting together for a story.

If you are worried about individual egghead spoilers who cannot lose themselves in the witty banter of your characters and your awesome alien scenarios, have such an egghead show up in your story to protest the wormhole as your acknowledgement of those concerns.  He can wear a white cravat, and the ladies like his accent.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create technology that could stabilize a wormhole as well as create a definite destination?

Based on our current knowledge wormholes are nothing more than a speculation like time travel.

As such we cannot know of any technology to support them. For that we would need equations describing their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The equations of general relativity have solutions for wormholes, but those solutions involve negative mass. Quantum physics kind of allows negitive mass, maybe a little bit. General relativity and quantum mechanics don't fit together mathematically. In short, we don't know enough physics to say whether or not wormholes are possible. 
We can say that if wormholes are possible, they are likely to have similar mass energy scales as black holes. Ie expect that you need VAST amounts of energy to create big ones. (You might be able to use mass.) The mass of the sun would make a wormhole a few km across. The mass used is proportional to radius. Tidal forces will probably be large enough to rip you apart unless the wormhole is far larger than that. Use tiny wormholes with high powered lasers for ftl comms.

Mind uploading is definitely possible under known physics, and probably a lot easier than wormholes. So make the spacecraft be rocket engines (nuclear or antimatter) plus a computer, and maybe humanoid robots. The computer simulates human minds in whatever virtual world makes sense. This might be a buttons and dials star ship bridge, if that is the best way to control the rockets. Sometimes the human minds get connected to the robot bodies to explore the ground on planets. All the hardware is left when you go through a wormhole, only the digital minds are beamed through, but hardware is cheep, nanotech can make anything in moments.

You do need a reason why this is being done by human minds. (It is hard to make a good story involving only AI's without anthropomorphising them.) Rules for dealing with supersmart AI's 1) The AI always gets what it wants. 2) What it wants is entirely a function of how it was programmed 3) What it was programmed to want might or might not be what the programmer wanted it to want.
Possible reasons for humans running rockets.

AI's can achive any precicely stated goal with superhuman skill, but they can't make difficult moral decisions and get the same answers that a human would get without simulating a human. The AI has been well programmed, it cares about human morality. But any part of its code that computes what is moral well enough to reliably get the right answer is actually quite similar to a simulated human. Difficult moral decisions need to be made, perhaps about the moral value of aliens, so the AI simulates some humans to make those decisions. The best moral philosophers humanity has to offer, on a bold mission to seek out alien life, and 
decide if it is sentient.

The AI does what humans want. These humans want to explore space. The AI could make totally realistic virtual planets much more easily, but these humans want to explore real planets, so the AI makes the tech needed. Meanwhile >99% of humanity has decided that virtual worlds are fine, and are living in a vast array of virtual worlds somewhere.

Either way, a copy of the AI will reside in the computer with them, and do tasks like steering through an asteroid field without hitting anything. (This is easy as asteroids are really spread out. ) But expect the story to be all charactor development and moral quagmires, no parts where the crew are struggling with some technical problem.

Comment: Just as a note: lots about AI and just a bit of wormholes in your answer.